# Get the last object returned

Tags: powershell

Occasionally I execute a PowerShell command and I forget to store its return values/objects in a variable. Does PowerShell store the returned object of the last command in a variable I could access to?

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem 
... 
PS C:\> # Oh no, I forgot to assign the output to a variable
PS C:\> $a = Get-ChildItem
PS C:\>
```

Comment: That would be a great feature for Interactive PowerShell. I find the similar Python interactive variable `_` to be very useful. *"In [Python] interactive mode, the last printed expression is assigned to the variable _."* From [Informal Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) - search page for "last printed expression"

Answer (score 8):

From [stuffing the output of the last command into an automatic variable](http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/06/25/Stuffing-the-output-of-the-last-command-into-an-automatic-variable.aspx): override [out-default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default?view=powershell-6) and store the results in a global variable called `$lastobject`.

For powershell 6 and newer:

```
function out-default {
  $input | Tee-Object -var global:lastobject | 
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\out-default
}
```

For powershell 5:

```
function out-default {
  $input | Tee-Object -var global:lastobject | 
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\out-default
}
```

And for both:

```
# In case you are using custom formatting
# You will need to override the format-* cmdlets and then
# add this to your prompt function

if($LastFormat){$LastOut=$LastFormat; $LastFormat=$Null }
```

Solution posted by Andy Schneider and inspired by comments from "//\o//" and Joel.

Comment: Actually Tanner, I think that is an excellent solution to the user's question. Link-Only answers are discouraged though. You should have copied the actual function and a brief explanation of it though because links can go down.

Comment: very interesting indeed, it hurts the performance but for a dev environment i would say its a fair tradeoff for the functionality provided

Comment: FWIW I'm using both PowerShell 7.3.11 and Windows PowerShell 5.1 in Windows Terminal, with this code in my $profile. Using `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` (as per the 5.1 example above) does _not_ work for either 7 or 5.1, but using `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core` _does_ work for both.

Answer (score 2):

Currently on WMF 5.1, it looks like `Out-Default` is in a different namespace.

```
function Out-Default {
    $Input | Tee-Object -Var Global:LastOutput |
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Out-Default
}
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment - however I've updated the main answer to include an example for newer Powershells.